# Implementing NSToolbar

Tags: objective-c, macos

Im trying to Implement my application with NSToolbar. I know I need to add the following, but I don't know where...

```
IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
```

Answer (score 2):

In Interface Builder, drag an `NSToolbar` from the library palette onto your window.  Voilà!  A toolbar!

Without more information, we can't be more specific.

Comment: I want to do it programmatically